# Anchored AJAX and SEO workaround?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, graceful-degradation, hashchange

You all know how to build AJAX sites with those 300ms trigger for checking anchors (hash links) in URL and then loading proper page with AJAX. But, these anchor links are nothing to search engines =(

I've thought of making some kind of workaround. All JS code remains the same, but, this little thing (I'm with JQuery, sorry):

```
$('a').live("click",function(){
    var lnk = $(this).attr("href");
    document.location.hash = lnk;
    return false;
})
```

And then, you replace your anchor links in the body with plain links, build corresponding plain pages (still containing all JS codes) for non-javascript users and search engines. For normal visitors you would have plain links converted into hashes on fly and AJAX content loaded immediately. For those who are trying to load certain pages found through search engine - they will, and after that visitor will continue to move around with ajax navigation... somehow (remember, those plain direct pages still contain JS code).

I just want to make sure my assumptions are right. Are they?

**Update:** Bad thing is that when user directly enters some internal page with for ex. */portfolio* address, he would then continue to */portfolio#contacts* or similar URLs that are not so pretty, but still working (I mean */portfolio#contacts* would show contacts).

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem to be a good approach mainly because you'll end up having that function being triggered for the `click` event of each and every link, even those where you do *not* want to use your AJAX approach for loading content, for instance links to other sites or to `javascript:...`.

If you place all your AJAX-y links under the same class or use another attribute to distinguish them and then adapt the jQuery selector that you're using there, then it will work and it will be a good approach because not only will it be SEO-friendly, but it also provides graceful degradation, that is, your users will still be able to access the content even if they're running in an environment where no JavaScript is allowed.

Other than that, and if SEO is your only concern, you may search the web for what a `sitemap.xml` file is and how to use it. Wikipedia has an [article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) that may be worth a reading.

Comment: Yes, specifying a class for these links is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds very sound... only I would suggest the callback on your 300ms timer also be called inside the event you have above, that way you have an instant result when clicking a link(and also a user can goto the link in the address bar and get the same effect)

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate, you probably want to check out [jQuery Ajaxy](http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/). It gracefully upgrades websites into rich ajax applications, so your website still works for SEO and Javascript disabled users.

You can see this functionality in action [in this upcoming website](http://staging.balupton.com/). Notice how all the links are the same as they would be if the website isn't a Ajax application - and they still work if you right click and go open in new window!

This functionality is explained in detail at it's demo page. You can also find other examples and usage instructions there to:
http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

Overall to use it is surprisingly simple and straightforward (especially considering what it allows you to do!), and the support is fantastic.